# using swatches instead of dropdowns 2.1

Tags: magento2, attributes, swatches, dropdown-attribute

Is there an option in admin to show swatches instead of drop downs?

I seem to remember there being an option in magento 1.9 to do this but can't seem to find it in admin here.

Just to clarify this is so that instead of drop down for sizes there will be boxes such as in this demo product page: http://magento2.demo.ubertheme.com/neve-studio-dance-jacket.html

---

ack found it immediately after in attributes>product

Actually that is for input in admin not for store front soo still same question